# less undefined method error

Tags: css, less

I have the following less compile error. My less is below not sure what is causing this.

```
undefined_methodError: error evaluating function `darken`: Object #<Object> has no method 'toHSL' in /Users/anderskitson/Sites/mrskitson.ca/wp-content/themes/wordpress-bootstrap/library/less/variables.less:164:34
163 @navbarBackground:                "../images/nav.png";
164 @navbarBorder:                    darken(@navbarBackground, 12%);
165

(This action was triggered by a change to navbar.less)
```

Less File

```
@navbarBackground: "../images/nav.png";
background: url("{@navbarBackground}");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-darken):

> **darken**
>
> Decrease the lightness of a color by an absolute amount.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `color`: A color object.
> - `amount`: A percentage 0-100%.
>
> Returns: `color`

The `darken` function wants a color but your `@navbarBackground` is a URL for a background image. You're getting a complaint about `toHSL` because LESS is trying to convert the color to the HSL format to make the darkening computation easier.

I don't know of any way to darken an image through LESS, you might need to manually darken the image and switch between them as needed.

Comment: Depending on your usage, you could use opacity coupled with a black background to achieve your 'darken' effect, and a white background to do a 'lighten' effect. inversely, you could overlay an opaque (white or black) div on the image.

Comment: Helped me a lot, though in my case ( to share for others ) - I had a `!default` inside my variable, `@incomplete:    #bbb !default;` so it was also - not just a color HEX ...

Answer (score -2):

You are missing an `@` in darken method, i.e.

```
@navbarBorder:darken(@navbarBackground, 12%);
```